# Faster way to count number of matching 2nd elements between two list of tuples? - Python

Tags: python, count, pattern-matching, tuples

Is there a faster way to count number of matching 2nd elements between two list of tuples?

I have tuples as such and i was basically looping through them one tuple at a time:

```
lstup1 = [('but', '00004722-r'), ('he', '000000NULL'), ('was', '02697725-v'), ('always', '00020280-r'), ('persuade', '00766418-v'), ('out', '02061487-a')]
lstup2 = [(u'But', u'000000NULL'), (u'he', u'000000NULL'), (u'was', u'000000NULL'), (u'always', u'00019339-r'), (u'persuade', u'00766418-v'), (u'out', u'00232862-r')]

for i,j in izip(lstup1,lstup2):
  if i[1] == j[1]:
    correct+=1
    if j[1][-4:] == "NULL"
      null+=1
  count+=1

print "Accuracy =", str(correct/count), "with", str(null), "NULL tags"
```

Comment: you can use a generator expression like this :`sum(i[1]==j[1] for i,j in zip(lstup1,lstup2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sets` here:

```
In [5]: se1=set(x[1] for x in lstup1)

In [6]: se2=set(x[1] for x in lstup2)

In [7]: len(se1&se2)
Out[7]: 2
```

Time complexity for intersection: `O(min(len(se1), len(se2))`

Time complexity for set creation: `O(L)` ,where `L` is length of list

Or your `izip()` version which compares only the items on same index can be reduced to:

```
sum(i[1]==j[1] for i,j in izip(lstup1,lstup2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lstup1 = [('but', '00004722-r'), ('he', '000000NULL'), ('was', '02697725-v'), ('always', '00020280-r'), ('persuade', '00766418-v'), ('out', '02061487-a')]
>>> lstup2 = [(u'But', u'000000NULL'), (u'he', u'000000NULL'), (u'was', u'000000NULL'), (u'always', u'00019339-r'), (u'persuade', u'00766418-v'), (u'out', u'00232862-r')]
>>> 
>>> npl1 = np.array(lstup1)
>>> npl2 = np.array(lstup2)
>>> npl1[:,1] == npl2[:,1]
array([False,  True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

If you just want to know the number of equal pairs:

```
>>> np.sum(npl1[:,1] == npl2[:,1])
2
```

If you want to know the index locations:

```
>>> np.where(npl1[:,1] == npl2[:,1])
(array([1, 4]),)
```